# How do I make a "Rotary hopper clock"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm working on a project that requires a fairly long delay. I found the ["Rotary hopper clock" on Minecraft 101](http://www.minecraft101.net/redstone/redstone-clocks.html), and I do like the compact design it has to it. However I'm not entirely sure how it works, and the article I found doesn't go very in-depth on it. I'm not really new to Redstone, but I haven't really gotten too far into it until now.

So, how exactly does it work (I'm not even sure where the output is), and how am I supposed to use it?

Here is a picture of it from the article:
[image: Rotary hopper clock]

Comment: What delay length do you need?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. I need it to be 30 to 45 seconds. I know that's not "long" in real time, but for setting delays (for me) it kind of is.

Comment: Is "silent" a design specification? If not, there's a much smaller and easier to configure design I know of. Though I'm sure it wouldn't be difficult to configure this design.

Comment: Hmm, a normal hopper timer could do that sort of delay. Look it up, I would answer but I'm on mobile.

Comment: @Unionhawk I'd prefer it if the timer didn't make too much noise, so I'd like it to be quiet/silent.  I'm interested in the smaller (and easier to configure) design. Could you give a link or name to it?

Comment: I'm going to work out the math on it. My personal favorite hopper timer is Etho's design

Comment: @Unionhawk That'd be great. If you want I can go on chat (The Bridge), and from there start a room. Only, because it's a little bit faster than the comment system. If not then we can just stick to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary design I use for a configurable timer (as of Minecraft 1.5) is Etho's hopper clock.

[image: Etho's hopper timer]

(there's no hidden redstone and both pistons are sticky, and the hoppers are facing into each other)

Unfortunately, unlike the other design, this one is not completely silent; there's a piston pulse every cycle of the timer. But the same mathematical principles apply to this design too.

Hoppers transfer items at a rate of 0.4 seconds per item, which means 0.4 seconds per item per half-cycle (0.4 seconds with the redstone block in one position, 0.4 seconds in the other). So with Etho's design, the formula for the number of items is `0.8 * items = seconds`. So if you want a pulse every 8 seconds, you need 10 items.

The design you show runs on the same principles, but with a repeater for each part-cycle, adding 1 redstone tick (0.1 second) per part-cycle. So the formula for this one is `1.6 * items + 0.4` seconds per full-cycle.

So assume only one hopper output is "on", and you want a signal of any length every 30 seconds. Doing the math gives a magic number of 18,5 items, so we'll use 19 and call it close enough. I did some in-game testing, and came up with 30 seconds, and it comes out to being about 15 on, 15 off.

The important bits:

- With the design you show, (4 hoppers in a circle) you can calculate the number of items needed by `(1.6 * items) + 0.4 = seconds`
- With Etho's design, shown above, you can calculate the number of items needed by `(0.8 * items = seconds`

Comment: Um, should the hopper be doing anything with the items inside of it? I built everything as you did, and the blocks (in the hopper) just sit there.

Comment: Here are some screenshots to show you: [this one](http://i.imgur.com/B7BqfHo.png), and [this one](http://i.imgur.com/a1l69nL.png).

Comment: @Scootaloo You need to point the hoppers into each other by shift+clicking on the other hopper when placing one (put a block there, place against the block, remove that block, shift+right click the other hopper so it points into it.)

Comment: I knew it had to be finnicky like that, thank you again. [I just noticed that little bend to it as well](http://i.imgur.com/9KxGkxd.png).

Comment: I think you should also add a screenshot so that people can also see the side of the hopper to see that it is connected. That's just a _very minor_ gripe with it though.